# Clojure: namespace and -main

Tags: clojure, namespaces, scope, program-entry-point, leiningen

I'm trying to understand the -main and its namespace settings. The default namespace in a -main function seems to be "user", but function defined "above" the main function, in the same file, can be called. Are they referred? I was running this to find out:

```
(ns ack.doodle)

(defn fo [] "bar")

(defn -main [& args]
  (println (fo))                               ;; bar
  (println *ns*)                               ;; #<Namespace user>
  (println (get (ns-refers *ns*) 'sorted-map)) ;; #'clojure.core/sorted-map
  (println (get (ns-refers *ns*) 'fo))         ;; nil
  (println (get (ns-map *ns*) 'fo))            ;; nil
  (println (get (ns-publics *ns*) 'fo))        ;; nil
  (println (get (ns-interns *ns*) 'fo))        ;; nil
  (println (get (ns-aliases *ns*) 'fo))        ;; nil
  (println (ns-resolve *ns* 'fo)))             ;; nil
```

The call (fo) succeeds, yet apparently the symbol 'fo is not known in the current namespace *ns*. What's going on?

This problem hit me when trying to pass the name of some function, along with some arguments, as command line arguments to -main.

#### steps to reproduce

- paste above code in a file ./src/ack/doodle.clj
- create ./project.clj with these contents:

  > (defproject ack "1" :main ack.doodle)
- run it:

  > lein run

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Didn't I answer this for you [last night in #clojure](https://refheap.com/paste/2298)? If there's something unsatisfying about the answer, you'll have to clarify your question.

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't read your answer yesterday, I think I got disconnected before I had a chance to read it. About an hour later I rejoined the channel and asked whether anyone had answered, but got no response. I didn't know it was possible to have a different namespace binding at compile time and runtime. Anyway  it's still not entirely clear to me why the (fo) call succeeds at runtime, even though apparently 'fo is not known in the current namespace at runtime. So maybe the question should rather be: How to determine whether a call to a function in \*ns\* will succeed?

Comment: Also, didn't know about the channel log. oops :D

Comment: The runtime value of `*ns*` has no bearing on function calls succeeding. At compile time, the compiler sees you're calling `foo`, looks it up in `*ns*` (which *is* bound at the time), and emits a reference to `ack.doodle/foo`. At runtime, that reference has already been resolved, and so the value of `*ns*` makes no difference (which is why it's no longer bound). I don't understand your clarified question though - "How to determine whether a call to a function in `*ns*` will succeed" doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I think I'm beginning to understand this a bit better (and yes, looking at it now, my clarified question does seem a bit pointless).

Comment: Page Not Found! Knowledge LOST!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like leiningen runs (-main) by calling it from user namespace like that: (ack.doodle/-main). Thus *ns* is bound to the user namespace.

Try running lein repl in your project root. Then run (-main) and see what happens. :)